# Ruby on Rails - images not loading on Firefox and Chrome but load correctly on Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome, firefox, asset-pipeline

I have tried so many alternatives to fix this and now I am not sure what else to do. 
I am using ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) and Rails 3.2.8

My homepage looks fine on Safari, but there are so many issues when I try loading it on Chrome or Firefox. [See the site here](http://www.thenewoutfitproject.com/) I can only imagine the mess it is in IE.

Update - Here are the issues:

1. Some image don't appear
2. The images that appear don't respond to their css class
3. When I try to follow the address to the image (appaddress/assets/image_name.jgp) - I get  broken image link on Chrome and a "This image cannot be displayed because it contain errors" on Firefox.

All these images however look pretty and well behaved on Safari.

Here is the view file (relevant parts only):

```
<div class="masthead">

        <h1 align="center"> <%= image_tag "logoBW6.png", class: "header-image" %></h1>
</div>
 <div class="span6 image-overlay">
               <h3 align="center"> 
           <%= cl_image_tag(@blogs.first.image,  :transformation =>[ 
            { :width => 650, :height => 615, :crop => :fill, 
             :gravity => :south}]) %></h3>
       <a href=<%= blog_path(@blogs.first) %>><h2 align="left" class="overlay overlay-background"><%= image_tag "empty_banner.png" %></h2><h2 class="overlay text-overlay"><%= @blogs.first.title%></h2></a>
       <br /><%= @blogs.first.post.first(50) %>...
      </div>
    <div class="span6 image-overlay">
               <h3 align="center"> 
           <%= cl_image_tag(@blogs.first(2)[1].image,  :transformation =>[ 
            { :width => 650, :height => 615, :crop => :fill, 
             :gravity => :south}]) %></h3>
       <a href=<%= blog_path(@blogs.first(2)[1]) %>><h2 align="left" class="overlay overlay-background"><%= image_tag "empty_banner.png" %></h2><h2 class="overlay text-overlay"><%= @blogs.first(2)[1].title%></h2></a>
       <br /><%= @blogs.first(2)[1].post.first(300) %>...
      </div>
 </div>
    </div>
```

Application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'csv'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Chic
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
     config.assets.prefix = "/assets"
  end
end
```

Production.rb

```
Chic::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "thenewoutfitproject.com" }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :ses

end
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks!
Sam

Comment: What issues are you experiencing exactly? Missing images? JavaScript error? If the first, have you tried following the broken links? Please update your post

Comment: Just did the update. I have tried following the images and it says it is broken or contain errors. I have a feeling it is all in the asset pipeline. The images that come from a model through a global variable work fine everywhere.

Comment: So what's weird, is I can view the image URL to your logo just fine in Safari and not in Chrome. Just to confirm are you sure the problem isn't the images themselves? Can you load the image locally in Chrome from your desktop? 
http://www.thenewoutfitproject.com/assets/logoBW6-8201290ead3ce359f983f218aa4d3856.png

Comment: Yes, that is my point - it works fine in Safari. So frustrating!!! And no, the image cannot be loaded on Chrome or Firefox, even locally. It works with safari. @creativereason

Comment: How are you creating the images? Are they "saved for web" incorrectly? So if you drag one from a finder or desktop window (or the Windows equivalent) into the browsers (not using the URL) it doesn't show up unless it's in Safari. This sounds like a corrupt image. Not an asset pipeline issue IMHO. Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I saved the images directly from photoshop into the assets/images folder for my ruby app. Is there another way to go about it for images that are not part of a model that I am not familiar with? @creativereason

Comment: Sorry, I think your misunderstanding my point. Sometimes if you choose the wrong file name or color profile in Photoshop the image can be corrupted. To confirm that isn't the case, can you drag the image from your Finder window into Chrome and Firefox does it show up? If it renders correctly, the problem is on your server /asset pipeline, if it doesn't render correctly the problem is in how you saved in Photoshop.

Comment: Ah-ha! Yes, the images are corrupted! They won't open on Chrome or Firefox. I guess I need to go back and save them again on photoshop to see if it will work.

Comment: There's definately something wrong with images. Asset pipeline is ok, url's are the same. In Chrome image shows up as broken but when I save it (from Chrome) I can open it in Preview (Mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images may be corrupted. Sometimes that can look like an asset pipeline error, but is really caused by accidentally using the wrong file name with Save for Web settings in Photoshop.